# Django - Field by Field Restrictions on Which Users Can view Certain Fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm learning Django and building a simple CRUD application.  I have a model for cars, and this contains a number of fields.  When a user loads a car page, I'd like some fields to be displayed and others hidden, depending on whether the user has a high enough score for the car they are viewing.  So for each field (engine, wheels, headlights, etc), or for some groups of fields, there would be a corresponding visibility score.  If the user's score for that particular car exceeded the visibility for a particular field, then the data for that field would be displayed in the view.

I could add a DecimalField variable for each component to denote this minimum score, the Car model would have a calc_score(user) method. In the view the current user's score would be compared against each of these, but I'm guessing there may be a better way to do this.  Can anyone recommend a better approach?

Thank you.

Comment: add your code whatever you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

You should just pass in the user's score as context when rendering the page from your views.py. It would look something like this:

```
def car_page_view(request):
    current_user_score = getUserScore()
    context = {
        'user_score': current_user_score
    }
    return render(request, 'car-page.html', context)
```

Then, in your html, put a check like this to only show certain elements:

```
{% if user_score > 10 %}
    <text>This text is only visible to users with scores higher than 10.</text>
{% endif %}
```

This is better than, say, loading all html elements and setting certain elements to "hidden". Instead, this causes the html you want hidden to never be loaded at all. So even if they use the inspect tool they won't see it :)

Comment: Checking the scores in the view or template is easy, but is there a better way to store the thresholds than the DecimalFields (eg min_score_for_engine_details = DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)?